# R base function points() can be duplicated

Tags: r

I have been trying to figure out why I can only see one of the two plots with the *points()* plotted.

```
set.seed(0)
SSE <- rep(0, 10)
for (i in 1:10){
  km.out <- kmeans(x = iris[,1:4], centers = 3, nstart = i)
  SSE[i] <- km.out$tot.withins
}
plot(1:10, SSE, xlab = "k", ylab = "SSE", type = "b")
km.out$cluster

plot(iris[,1:2], col=(km.out$cluster+1), main="Best solution k = 3", xlab="x1", ylab="x2")
points(km.out$centers, col = 1:2, pch = 8, cex = 2)

plot(iris[,3:4], col=(km.out$cluster+1), main="Best solution k = 3", xlab="x1", ylab="x2")
points(km.out$centers, col = c3:4, pch = 8, cex = 2) # didn't work, not sure why
```

> First plot has the points.

[image: First plot]

> Second plot with no points plotted.

[image: Second plot]

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: theres a `c` in the `points(km.out$centers, col = c3:4, pch = 8, cex = 2)` in the col section, coud that be it? Also it looks like the points you're trying to plot are outside the range of the graph somehow

Comment: Ahh, true, that was a typo. :)  I wonder why the points are outside of the range.  Unfortunately I am very new to clustering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The points are outside the range of the graph. Increase the ylim like this:

```
 plot(iris[,3:4], col=(km.out$cluster+1), main="Best solution k = 3", xlab="x1", ylab="x2", ylim=c(0,4))
 points(km.out$centers, col = 3:4, pch = 8, cex = 2)
```

An you'll see everything.

Or adjust the points themselves:

```
 points(km.out$centers[, 3:4], col = 3:4, pch = 8, cex = 2)
```

[image]

Comment: Interesting, out of curiosity, how did you know they were out of range?

Comment: I looked at the points you were trying to plot. The axis difference between the graphs was my first clue though

Comment: Ah, true, I just figured out what you meant, thanks mate :)